# How to write a String to the STDIN of another Process in FreePascal

Tags: multiprocessing, pipe, freepascal

My most common Use Cases require that Error and Execution Reports are send to the System Administrator by Email.
In Bash you would use the Pipe `|` Operator as in:

```
echo "test mail" | mail -s "Mail Command Test" admin@domain.com
```

Now I'm seeking to apply the this Concept to FreePascal with the `TProcess` Class.

How can I write the Report String to the `mail` subprocess?

I found the Information at 
https://wiki.freepascal.org/Executing_External_Programs
But I does not exactly describe my Use Case since there isn't a first process

---

To explain the Problematic of the Operators `| < >` **not working**
and Option `shell=true` (from *Python* `subprocess.Popen`) **not existing** as documented at:
[Replacing shell operators](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Executing_External_Programs#Replacing_shell_operators_like_.22.7C_.3C_.3E.22)

I wrote a little *Perl* Script as Mailer Dummy:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w


use strict;



my $ipid = $$;
my $smessage = '';
my $log = '';


print "prms (cnt: '" . scalar(@ARGV) . "'):\n";

$log .= "prms (cnt: '" . scalar(@ARGV) . "'):\n";

foreach(@ARGV)
{
  print "prm: '$_'\n";

  $log .= "prm: '$_'\n";
}

while(<STDIN>)
{
  $smessage  .= $_ ;
}

print "message: '$smessage'\n";

$log .= "message: '$smessage'\n";


print "log: writing ...\n";

$log =~ s#"#\"#g;

print "log msg:\n'$log'\n";

system("echo -e \"${log}\" > ./mailer-perl_${ipid}.log");


exit 0;
```

This will show the Parameters and the Content of the `STDIN` passed to the Child Process.

1. Now when I create my `TProcess` Object as follows:

```pascal
  mailcommand := TProcess.Create(nil);

  try
    try
      mailcommand.Options    := [poUsePipes, poStderrToOutPut];
      mailcommand.Executable := 'mailer.pl';
      mailcommand.Parameters.Add('-s "Mail Command Test" user_login@localhost < mail_message.txt');

      mailcommand.Execute;

      // Close the input on the SecondProcess
      // so it finishes processing it's data
      mailcommand.CloseInput;

      // and wait for it to complete

      bwait := mailcommand.WaitOnExit;

      WriteLn('Mail Command WaitOnExit: ', chr(39), bwait, chr(39));

   except
      on e : Exception do
      begin
        WriteLn('Mail Command - failed with Exception [', e.HelpContext, ']: '
          , chr(39), e.Message, chr(39));

        //e.Free;
      end //on E : Exception do
      else
      begin
        WriteLn('Mail Command - failed with Unknown Exception: '
          , chr(39), 'unknown error', chr(39));
      end;  //on e : Exception do
    end;
  finally
    // free our process objects
    mailcommand.Free;
  end;
```

I can observe this Activity in the Child Process:

```
prms (cnt: '1'):
prm: '-s "Mail Command Test" user_login@localhost < mail_message.txt'
message: ''
```

There is **NO** Message on the `STDIN`.
Everything was send as **1 Single Parameter** to the Child Process!

2. I create the `TProcess` Object as follows:

```pascal
  mailcommand := TProcess.Create(nil);

//[...]
      mailcommand.Options    := [poUsePipes, poStderrToOutPut];
      mailcommand.Executable := 'mailer.pl';
      mailcommand.Parameters.Add('-s');
      mailcommand.Parameters.Add('Mail Command Test');
      mailcommand.Parameters.Add('user_login@localhost');
      mailcommand.Parameters.Add('<');
      mailcommand.Parameters.Add('mail_message.txt');
//[...]
```

Then I observe this Activity in the Child Process:

```
prms (cnt: '5'):
prm: '-s'
prm: 'Mail Command Test'
prm: 'user_login@localhost'
prm: '<'
prm: 'mail_message.txt'
message: ''
```

Again there is **NO** Message on the `STDIN`
the Symbol " *<* " was just passed as **another Parameter** to the Child Process.

The `TProcess` Class **does not have** and `shell=true` Option as you might suppose it from *Python* from the Module of the similar Name.

Comment: If I understand your question, you could use `ReadLn` and pipe data to your program.

Answer (score 1):

Studing the *FreePascal* Architecture I understood that the `|` functionality is implemented with `TProcess.Input` Property which indeed is a `TOutputPipeStream`.

The `TOutputPipeStream` is the objectoriented implementation of the wellknown `pipe`
https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/fcl/pipes/toutputpipestream.html

> `TOutputPipeStream` is created by the `CreatePipeStreams` call to
>   represent the writing end of a pipe. It is a `TStream` descendent which
>   does not allow reading.

So to `TStream` Objects you can write with the `TStream.Write()` Function.

Since the `echo` Command in `bash` just prints a Text out I simply replaced it by a `TStringStream` which grows dynamically and results into a Pascal `String`. This it comes handy for progressive report generation. The resulting Pascal `String` you can use directly and write it into the `TProcess.Input` Stream.

**Note:** You need to call `TProcess.Execute` before you can write into the Input Stream because this is the moment with the System `fork()` Call happens and the `pipe` is open.
But yet the `TProcess` is not running because it waits still for the `STDIN` Input.

```
program mail_pipe;

uses
Classes, sysutils, process;

var
  mailcommand: TProcess;
  messagestream: TStringStream;
  smessage: String;
  sbuffer: String;
  ReadSize: Integer;
  bwait: Boolean;
begin
  mailcommand := TProcess.Create(nil);
  messagestream := TStringStream.Create('');

  try
    try
      smessage := 'test mail';

      messagestream.WriteString(smessage);

      // this would be the same as 'mail -s "Mail Command Test" admin@domain.com'
      mailcommand.Options    := [poUsePipes, poStderrToOutPut];
      mailcommand.Executable := 'mail';
      mailcommand.Parameters.Add('-s');
      mailcommand.Parameters.Add('Mail Command Test');
      mailcommand.Parameters.Add('user_login@localhost');

      mailcommand.Execute;

      WriteLn('Mail Input: Writing ...');

      WriteLn('Mail Input (Length ', chr(39), messagestream.Size, chr(39), '):');
      WriteLn(chr(39), messagestream.DataString, chr(39));
      mailcommand.Input.Write(messagestream.DataString[1], messagestream.Size);
      //mailcommand.Input.Write(PChar(''), 0);

      // Close the input on the SecondProcess
      // so it finishes processing it's data
      mailcommand.CloseInput;

      // and wait for it to complete

      bwait := mailcommand.WaitOnExit;

      WriteLn('Mail Command WaitOnExit: ', chr(39), bwait, chr(39));

      // that's it! the rest of the program is just so the example
      // is a little 'useful'

      // we will reuse Buffer to output the SecondProcess's
      // output to *this* programs stdout
      WriteLn('Mail Output: Reading ...');

      sbuffer := '';

      ReadSize := mailcommand.Output.NumBytesAvailable;

      WriteLn('Mail Report (Length ', chr(39), ReadSize, chr(39), '):');

      SetLength(sbuffer, ReadSize);

      if ReadSize > 0 then
      begin
        mailcommand.Output.Read(sbuffer[1], ReadSize);

        WriteLn(chr(39), sbuffer, chr(39));
      end;

      WriteLn('Mail Command finished with [', mailcommand.ExitStatus, ']');
    except
      //------------------------
      //Report Exception

      on e : Exception do
      begin
        WriteLn('Mail Command - failed with Exception [', e.HelpContext, ']: '
          , chr(39), e.Message, chr(39));
      end //on E : Exception do
      else
      begin
        WriteLn('Mail Command - failed with Unknown Exception: '
          , chr(39), 'unknown error', chr(39));
      end;  //on e : Exception do
    end;

  finally
    // free our process objects
    messagestream.Free;
    mailcommand.Free;
  end;

end.
```

Actually you can observe in the `strace` log that the `TProcess` creates Pipes, does the lookup of the `mail` Command and forks it from the Main Process:

```
strace: Process 11860 attached
restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted nanosleep ...>) = 0
mmap(NULL, 32768, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7e8e3c0000
pipe([3, 4])                            = 0
pipe([5, 6])                            = 0
access("mail", F_OK)                    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 32768, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7e8e3b8000
access("/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin/mail", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/local/bin/mail", F_OK)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/local/sbin/mail", F_OK)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/bin/mail", F_OK)           = 0
fork()                                  = 13921
close(4)                                = 0
close(5)                                = 0
write(1, "Mail Input: Writing ...\n", 24) = 24
write(1, "Mail Input (Length '9'):\n", 25) = 25
write(1, "'test mail'\n", 12)           = 12
write(6, "test mail", 9)                = 9
close(6)                                = 0
wait4(13921, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 13921
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=13921, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
write(1, "Mail Command WaitOnExit: 'TRUE'\n", 32) = 32
write(1, "Mail Output: Reading ...\n", 25) = 25
ioctl(3, FIONREAD, [0])                 = 0
write(1, "Mail Report (Length '0'):\n", 26) = 26
write(1, "Mail Command finished with [0]\n", 31) = 31
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f7e8e3e0000, 32768)           = 0
munmap(0x7f7e8e3d8000, 32768)           = 0
munmap(0x7f7e8e3d0000, 32768)           = 0
munmap(0x7f7e8e3e8000, 32768)           = 0
munmap(0x7f7e8e3c8000, 32768)           = 0
munmap(0x7f7e8e3c0000, 32768)           = 0
munmap(0x7f7e8e3b8000, 32768)           = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

The Output from the Program mail_pipe is:

```
$ ./mail_pipe
Mail Input: Writing ...
Mail Input (Length '9'):
'test mail'
Mail Command WaitOnExit: 'TRUE'
Mail Output: Reading ...
Mail Report (Length '0'):
Mail Command finished with [0]
```

This is a normal and expected Output since `mail` only would give an Output if it failed. Further details on the EMail Processing you can find in your local `maillog`.

As Result you get an EMail in your **Local Mailbox**:

```
Delivered-To: user_login@localhost
Received: by user-workstation (Postfix, from userid 1000)
    id E977140439D4C; Tue, 31 Mar 2020 08:31:42 +0100 (WEST)
Date: Tue, 31 Mar 2020 08:31:42 +0100
To: user_login@localhost
Subject: Mail Command Test
User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.5 7/5/10
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Message-Id: <20200331073142.E977140439D4C@user-workstation>
From: user_login (User Name)

test mail=
```

Important when writing Pascal `String`s to a Stream is that due to the **Memory Outlay** of the Pascal `String`s the Data starts at **Position 1** as in:

```
SecondProcess.Input.Write(messagestream.DataString[1], messagestream.Size);
```

---

**Possible Errors:**

- If `TProcess.Executable` **does not exist** an `Exception` will be
  thrown:

```
$ ./mail_pipe
Mail Command - failed with Exception [0]: 'Executable not found: "no_script.pl"'
```

This might happen if the `mail` Command is not installed on the system.

- If `TProcess.Executable` **is not executable** a `SIGCHLD` Signal will be
  generated:
  (And if the Application proceeds to write to the then broken `pipe` a `SIGPIPE` Signal will be generated.)

```
strace: Process 24911 attached restart_syscall(<...
resuming interrupted nanosleep ...>) = 0 mmap(NULL, 32768,
PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) =
0x7ff970770000 pipe([3, 4])                            = 0 pipe([5,
6])                            = 0 access("noexec_script.pl", F_OK)  
= 0 fork()                                  = 27068 close(4)                                = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=27068, si_uid=1000, si_status=127, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} --- close(5)     
= 0 write(1, "Mail Input: Writing ...\n", 24) = 24 write(1, "Mail Input (Length '9'):\n", 25) = 25 write(1, "'test mail'\n", 12)       
= 12 write(6, "test mail", 9)                = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
--- SIGPIPE {si_signo=SIGPIPE, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=24911, si_uid=1000} ---
+++ killed by SIGPIPE +++
```

This could happen if the Application does not have Permission to interact with this Command (perhaps `SELinux` might block it).

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe avoid writing to pipe directly, but solve your problem by writing your data to `msgfile` and then run exec with input redirection - `send <msgfile`...

As far as I understand pipes are created outside of your application and they redirect your program's output to other program's input `a | b` should be same as `a >file && b <file`. If you realy do not want to wait for send to finish, you can create separate thread which writes to file and then runs `send <msgfile` and terminates when it's done.

Another alternative might be to talk directly to mail server to send email and I suppose that there are units to do this...

Comment: Thank you for your input. Yes, when a Linux Programmer thinks of the task the first thought is that of Redirecting the Input and Output, because it mostly works in all Main Scripting Languages _Bash_, _Python_ and _Perl_. But at the Official Documentation https://wiki.freepascal.org/Executing_External_Programs#Replacing_shell_operators_like_.22.7C_.3C_.3E.22 it is clearly explained that the `TProcess` Class is **NOT** a _bash shell_ and thus won't work like this. But I'm still intrigued to see your Prototype how you achieve to make this work.

Comment: The _Shell_ instruction `command &` means in this way to run the command in detached manner that the comand won't block the terminal. Example `$ echo "hello world" &` the result is the _PID_ of the detached process: `[1] 29152`

Comment: Sorry, that ampersand was my attempt to wite < and > for io redirection in stackoverflow interface. I wanted to say that if you write your mail content to file named 'sendfile', then you can run something like 'mail -s "Mail Command Test" admin@domain.com <sendfile' to send it ...

Comment: maybe you can just use something like `exec ('send <msgfile')` to run external program?

Comment: Please, look my Examples that I added to the Question to demonstrate the Issue to fully understand the Problematic

Comment: Dear Bodo, you might check that there are no spaces betwen `<` and file name. cheers robby

Answer (score 0):

Here are two programms communicating via files. Second one starts first one via bash and redirects his input to previously created file:

```
program pr;
var s : string;
begin
  readln  (s);
  writeln (s)
end.

program test;
uses process;
var f : text; s : ansistring;
begin
  assign (f,'text');
  rewrite (f);
  writeln (f,'content');
  close (f);
  runcommand ('/bin/bash',['./pr <text'],s)
end.
```

working on os x, should work on linux and for windows you can use unit dos and exec ...

Comment: Thank you for your time and your effort that you put into this issue. Your solution might actually compile and also work. But apart from not being an idiomatic solution and rather a `bash` written in _Pascal_ it has several issues. **1)** It cannot handle more than **256 Bytes** **2)** It introduces the **overhead** of launching another Process which is the `bash shell` **3)** The Buffer Size is also limited to **256 Bytes**

Comment: Hi Bodo, this was just the sample to demonstrate concept. I suppose that input to mail comand is in range of 256 chars per line, if you need more you can make file with custom data type and read/write it with just a one read/write. Idomaticaly speaking - file emulates pipe, you can run mail insted of bash, and you can write whatewer you want to file (not limited to 256 bytes). As of overhead, if you want to use pipes (soluton working only on unix-es and not windoze) you'll already have mail process running all the time on the other end of pipe..